# Are the props in a Vue component mutable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mutable, vue-props

Folks! Recently, I am working on a Vue.js project, and I would like to split it into small components as much as possible. There is a component that renders a list from the parent component, and I'd like to change some properties on some action from the props. At this point, I am just curious if the props variable is mutable or not in a Vue.js component.

Here is a example code for better understand:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div
            class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 justify-between"
            v-for="(option, index) in options"
            :key="index"
        >
            <b-input-group>
                <b-input-group-prepend>
                    <b-button variant="secondary">
                        <b-icon icon="grip-horizontal"></b-icon>
                    </b-button>
                </b-input-group-prepend>

                <b-form-input
                    placeholder="Option"
                    @input="updateOption(index, $event)"
                    :value="option.answer"
                ></b-form-input>

                <b-input-group-append>
                    <b-button variant="secondary" @click="removeOption(index)">
                        Remove
                    </b-button>
                </b-input-group-append>
            </b-input-group>
            <b-form-checkbox
                :id="`option-${index}`"
                name="options"
                class="f-14 text-muted ml-1"
                v-model="option.correct"
            >
                Correct?
            </b-form-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'multi-options',
    props: ['options'],
    methods: {
        updateOption(index, value) {
            this.options[index].answer = value // Should this work or not?
        },
        removeOption(index) {
            this.options.splice(index, 1)
        },
        addOption() {
            this.options.push({
                answer: '',
                correct: false,
            })
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 2):

No, never. Vue js communication between parent/children is one way. Props received from parents should NEVER be mutated, otherwise, you will receive a warning if you are working with strict mode enabled.

Data from parents to children must be sent as `props`. Data from children to parent must be sent within `events`

The best approach here is to manipulate the data locally in your child component, by setting a local data when the component is mounted, and then emitting an event to the parent when something changes (only if you need to let the parent know that something happened)

```
props: ['options'],

data: () => ({
    local_options: []
}),

mounted () {
    this.local_options = [ ...this.options]
},

watch: {
   options: function () {
       deep: true,
       handler () {
          this.local_options = [ ...this.options]
       }
   }
},

methods: {
   updateOption(index, value) {
       this.local_options[index].answer = value
       this.$emit('updated', this.local_options)
   },

   removeOption(index) {
       this.local_options.splice(index, 1)
       this.$emit('updated', this.local_options)
   },

   addOption() {
       this.local_options.push({
           answer: '',
           correct: false,
       })
       this.$emit('updated', this.local_options)
   },
},
```

Then in your parent, where you have your child component, you can do something as per the child event:

```
<multi-options-component :options="options" @updated="doSomething" />

....
methods: {
    doSomething (options) {
         // Some logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to derive the `local_options` from the prop inside each method instead of having it derived on `mounted` hook for 2 reasons:
1. You have to manually ensure both options are synced at all times, which means you're basically losing the reactivity advantage that Vue provides. For e.g. `doSomething` may fail for some reason and now you have `local_options` out of sync.
2. If your child component updates from parent component for any reason (for e.g. `options` is updated), `mounted` will not be called again, so you have a problem.

Comment: Good catch, I've added a deep watcher for options props so in case that parent updates the options child will also do it.

Comment: I've added another answer as to why this is a bad idea for many reasons, and a better way to do it. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the way [@Luciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2330666/luciano) prefers having a separate local state for the child and manually maintaining its reactivity is a recipe for disaster (not to mention its way overkill considering Vue already has reactivity built-in). I have mentioned this in the comments, I'll add here again:

1. If `doSomething` fails for *any* reason, then the parent's `options` array won't get updated, whereas `local_options` array has already been updated within the component. Now parent and local states are out of sync and you have problem.
2. There is no need to use deep `watcher` inside every reusable component you build. If you have hundreds of such child components, you'll have performance hits and you're unnecessarily consuming a lot of memory creating and maintaining a separate local state for each child component.
3. You're losing the reactivity advantage that Vue provides in trying to manually ensure (albeit in an error-prone way) the local state is always in sync with the parent. That's not how you're supposed to use Vue.js.

So I'm adding another answer that's better than my previous answer in terms of reusability and DRY principle, while also being simple and chaos-free:

You need to pass an array back to the parent along with a single custom `update` event, but instead of creating this array in the `mounted` lifecycle hook, you create it on the go in each method:

```
props: ['options'],

methods: {
   updateOption(index, value) {
       let local_options = [ ...this.options]
       local_options[index].answer = value
       this.$emit('update', local_options)
   },

   removeOption(index) {
       let local_options = [ ...this.options]
       local_options.splice(index, 1)
       this.$emit('update', local_options)
   },

   addOption() {
       let local_options = [ ...this.options]
       local_options.push({
           answer: '',
           correct: false,
       })
       this.$emit('update', local_options)
   },
},
```

Then update your parent component's `option` data when the child emits an `update` event with `v-on:` directive or its shorthand `@`

```
<multi-options :options="options" @update="handleUpdate" />

....
methods: {
    handleUpdate(options) {
         this.options = options; // this reassignment re-renders the child component
    }
}
```

EDIT: I missed that you're using `v-model` on a prop in `<b-form-checkbox>` element with `v-model="option.correct"`. This will create a two way binding with the prop since it translates to `:checked="option.correct" @change="option.correct = $event"`. Which means you're mutating the prop inside child component. Do this instead:

```html
            <b-form-checkbox
                :id="`option-${index}`"
                name="options"
                class="f-14 text-muted ml-1"
                :checked="option.correct"
                @change="setOptionsCorrect(index, $event)"
            >
                Correct?
            </b-form-checkbox>
```

add the method under your `methods`:

```
setOptionsCorrect(index, value) {
    let local_options = [ ...this.options]
    local_options[index].correct = value
    this.$emit('update', local_options)
}
```

EDIT 2: If you insist on using `v-model` for style preferences, you could have a computed property derive from the options. But you'll need a separate setter that emits the event to parent, otherwise you'll run into the same "mutating props" problem

```
computed : {
    computedOptions: {
        get: function() {
            return this.options
        },
        set: function(newOptions) {
            this.$emit("update", newOptions)
        }
    }
},
methods: {
   updateOption(index, value) {
       let local_options = [ ...this.options]
       local_options[index].answer = value
       this.options = local_options
   },

   removeOption(index) {
       let local_options = [ ...this.options]
       local_options.splice(index, 1)
       this.options = local_options
   },

   addOption() {
       let local_options = [ ...this.options]
       local_options.push({
           answer: '',
           correct: false,
       })
       this.options = local_options
   },
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense, as soon as you change a bonded property such as v-model=option.correct in your child component, you will be directly mutating the props before emitting the event.

Comment: @Luciano Which is why you should never have v-model on a prop, it creates two way bindings. Check the edit to my answer

Comment: So you suggest not use v-model directive and handle everything in one-way data binding? I thought that you wanted to take advantage of reactivity... the local data could be set in the initial data state if you prefer, but what you are doing here just will ends in a messy spaghetti code for big components. Please, read the docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: Sure if OP wants to simply pass options as initial value and then not update the prop in parent component, as the doc says, then setting it in the data function is the right way (not in mounted hook, not with deep watchers). But OP wants the component's state to be in sync with parent component's options array, in that case this is not how you should do it. I'm taking advantage of Vue reactivity by having the component update on prop change by binding it to the prop instead of local_options. Could you please elaborate more on how this will end up spaghetti code? I'm eager to learn :)

Comment: Also, the `computed` property from docs is a good idea, except we'll have to add getters and setters to it to make it work in OPs case. I'll add this way to my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to mutate props from the component itself. From [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow), this is to prevent child component from accidentally mutating parent components state, which can make your app's data flow harder to understand.

What you can do instead is emit custom events from child component:

```
updateOption(index, value) {
    this.$emit("myUpdateEvent", { index, value });
}
removeOption(index) {
    this.$emit("myRemoveEvent", { index });
}
addOption() {
    this.$emit("myAddEvent");
}
```

Then listen to them in the parent component and make changes to the original array that you're passing to the child component as props.

```
<multi-options @myAddEvent="handleAddEvent()" @myUpdateEvent="handleUpdateEvent($event.index, $event.value)" @myRemoveEvent="handleRemoveEvent($event.index)" :options="myOptions"/>
```

```
data() {
    return {
        myOptions: [],
    }
},
methods: {
    handleUpdateEvent(index, value) {
        this.myOptions[index].answer = value
    },
    handleRemoveEvent(index) {
        this.myOptions.splice(index, 1);
    },
    handleAddEvent() {
        this.myOptions.push({
                answer: '',
                correct: false,
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, but you are coupling your components by adding logic to the parent. In terms of reusability, the child should manipulate the array and send back the mutated data to the parent.

Comment: Right, didn't think of that when I wrote the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I've added a new answer showing better way of doing this while solving problems in both of our answers